# Value of type any->(0) has no member isEnabled in swift ios10

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

why is this happing?  I am new to swift

I want record.isEnabled = false but I get this error why?

> Value of type any->(0) has no member isEnabled

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?

    @IBAction func record(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
       record.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: where you declare the `record`,

Comment: record is my button.  if if I click the the button stop I want to set the record button to be enabled

Comment: are you created the iboutlet for your button

Comment: You have issue that is connected with **record** because it is  `@IBAction` not `@IBOutlet.`

For solving of this issue drag outlet from storyboard and connect it with proper file.

Comment: yes --->>>> @IBAction func record

Comment: @Leo - the question is not related to duplicate answer , shall I reopen it

Comment: *"record is my button"* - no it isn't. There is no button in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh i see!!!!!!!!!  Yes I added an outlet thanks!!!!!

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: The initial version of the question was a duplicate, it was then edited. – There is no need for the [swift3] tag here, this is not a "question  directly related to changes in Swift 3".

Answer (score 1):

issue that you are  connected the **record** button in @**IBAction** not **@IBOutlet**. solving of this issue drag **outlet**  for **record** button from storyboard and connect it with proper file.

for e.g .

```
@IBOutlet weak var record: UIButton! // create the property for your button
```

full code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?

    @IBOutlet weak var record: UIButton!


    @IBAction func record(_ sender: UIButton!) {

        sender.isEnabled = false

    }
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {

       record.isEnabled = true

    }
    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      record.isEnabled = true  

    }
}
```